# Failure to read jpeg files in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to open images with imread but it keEps telling me that the files do not exist.

Here's the message from the command window

```
   Error using imread>get_full_filename (line 516)
   File "Pic1.jpg" does not exist.

   Error in imread (line 340)
       fullname = get_full_filename(filename);

   Error in ImageDetection (line 2)
   img1 = imread('Pic1.jpg');
```

And here are the sections of code that it's referencing from the function itself

```
       if (fid == -1)

       if ~isempty(dir(filename))
       % String 'Too many open files' is from strerror.
       % So, no need for a message catalog.
       if contains(errmsg, 'Too many open files')            
           error(message('MATLAB:imagesci:imread:tooManyOpenFiles', filename));
       else
        error(message('MATLAB:imagesci:imread:fileReadPermission', filename));
       end
    else
     error(message('MATLAB:imagesci:imread:fileDoesNotExist', filename));<--LINE 516
    end
```

---

```
if isempty(fmt_s)
   % The format was not specified explicitly.

   % Get the absolute path of the file
   fullname = get_full_filename(filename);  <--LINE 340
```

Comment: What folder is MATLAB currently operating in? It'll be listed near the top of your MATLAB window, and could read similar to "C:\Users\[Your User]\Documents\MATLAB", but it can be any folder on your computer. Then, where is the picture located on your computer?

Comment: How does this help?

Comment: Your error message is saying that the files don't exist. There's a few reasons why that would happen, but the most common two would be misspelled file names and incorrect directories. I'm guessing you spelled "Pic1.jpg" the same as the file, but if the picture file isn't in your working directory, MATLAB won't be able to find it. I was asking for the two locations so I could tell you specifically what options you have to reference the image file.

Comment: That was very helpful and it fixed the issue. I created a new folder in which I put the images and the script and now it runs just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course! I was trying to get clarification but since I accidentally answered it in the comments, I just posted an actual 'answer' below.

Answer (score 2):

### Image isn't in Current Directory (Or Path)

If your image is in your working directory, you can call it by its name ("Pic1.jpg"). However, MATLAB doesn't search all folders on your computer. If, for example, if your program is running in `C:\Users\user\Documents\MATLAB`, and the image is in `C:\Users\user\Pictures`, you could reference the picture using:

1. Absolute paths (`"C:\Users\user\Pictures\Pic1.jpg"`)
2. Relative paths (`"..\..\Pictures\Pic1.jpg"`)

Usually, if the pictures only exist because of your program, it'd be somewhere in the same directory, so you wouldn't need to use `".."` to move up any directories.

If you want the user to be able to select a picture each time the program is run, I'd recommend looking into [uigetfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html). If you want to know more about where MATLAB searches for files, see [this article](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/files-and-folders-that-matlab-accesses.html).

---

Secondly, you may want to check your file name. While it seems obvious, a simple misspelling can be hard to notice at times, for example "Pic1.jpg" vs "Pic1,jpg" vs "Pic1.jpeg"

Answer (score 0):

Just above the line of your code where the error occurs, write a new line:

```
dir
```

To output in the prompt the files of the current folder, and check that the name of your file exactly appears there. Could you copy us that output?

Comment: This is what I get when I run dir in the command workspace                             
 >> dir

+simiam              BE4337_HW_5_Q_5_2.m  README.md            resources            
.                    ImageDetection.m     bundled              settings.xml         
..                   LICENSE              coursera.xml         
.gitignore           Pic1.jpg             launch.m             
AUTHORS              Pic2.jpg             manual

Comment: I created files for each image and here's  the new error message I'm getting  
Error using imread>get_format_info (line 491)
Unable to determine the file format.

Error in imread/call_format_specific_reader (line 422)
                fmt_s = get_format_info(fullname);

Error in imread (line 403)
    [X, map] = call_format_specific_reader();

Error in ImageDetection (line 2)
img1 = imread('Pic1.jpg');